How to tail remote systemd journal files
I've gotten my systemd-journald-remote.service up and running, with (1) test client connecting successfully via systemd-journald-upload.service. When I normally tail journald logs, I use journalctl -fxb. I tried the same with the remote journald file, using:
sudo journalctl -fxb --file=/var/log/journal/remote/remote-192.168.122.22.journal

and it also works.
Here is the problem: while the remote system is running, everything works as expected. However, when the remote system reboots, the remote server logs are still being forwarded, but the current tail stops updating. A restart of the tail command works, but I'd like to avoid doing this, especially when I want to add about 30+ systems.
What am I doing wrong>


What am I doing wrong

You're specifying the -b option, which explicitly asks journalctl to limit its filter to the "current boot", which is detected by the "boot ID" UUID included with each message.
The boot ID is generated by the kernel and exposed through /proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id, which the remote system's journald will read on startup and attach to each message as _BOOT_ID, which you can see in journalctl's -o verbose output.
When you specify -b together with a journal file, your journalctl scans the log file to find the most recent message, takes the _BOOT_ID field from it, and sets up a filter to get only messages corresponding to that boot. For example:
$ SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug journalctl -f -b --file=$PWD/system.journal
File /var/log/journal/asdf/system.journal added.
Found boot ID 9881c6da57d24994a0989fba0a10fd4a by offset 0
Found boot 9881c6da57d24994a0989fba0a10fd4a for +0
Journal filter: _BOOT_ID=9881c6da57d24994a0989fba0a10fd4a

After the remote system reboots, its messages will have a different _BOOT_ID and of course will no longer match the filter. To avoid that, do not use the -b option.
(Using -b together with -f makes very little sense in any case, as each boot generates hundreds of messages during startup and therefore the initial 10-line "tail" of the messages will automatically be from the current boot anyway.)

I thought that would be the solution, but alas it failed, same as before. Running the same command as in the OP, sans the -b option, results in the tail freezing when the guest reboots. Restarting the tail always works.
